# How to create environment variables in Github Actions using other variables

Tags: yaml, github-actions

I want to use the GITHUB_SHA with a variable, like this:

```
name: build
on: ["push"]

env:
  PACKAGE: package-$GITHUB_SHA
```

But, when I use, yaml does not expand the variable and I got the string. How I can do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/contexts-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#github-context:

```
As part of an expression, you may access context information using one of two syntaxes.

Index syntax: github['sha']
Property dereference syntax: github.sha
```

In this case:

```
name: build
on: ["push"]

env:
  PACKAGE: package-${{ github.sha }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
name: build
on: ["push"]

env:
  PACKAGE: package-${{ github.sha }}
```

Comment: Almost there. The correct answer is `VM_NAME: ubuntu-env-${{ github.sha }}`

Update your answer, so I can give u kudos

Comment: This won't work because `GITHUB_SHA` is not defined in the context but rather in the environment